# Build Heroku apps automatically on every push to Github

Tags: github, heroku, heroku-ci

I want to enable automatic builds on Heroku anytime I push to `master` branch on GitHub just like Heroku would do whenever I push to a branch that is connected to an app on their platform. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this feat with [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions). We can automate builds on Heroku whenever a push is made hence no need to worry about deploying to Heroku via heroku-cli.

At the root of your application, create a .github folder.

Inside of the .github folder, create a workflow folder

lastly, in the workflow folder, create a yaml file. I'll call mine build-heroku-app.yml. So the file structure is going to look like so:

```
my-awesome-app
 - .github
    - workflow
       - build-heroku-app.yml
```

In build-heroku-app.yml file

```
# .github/workflows/build-heroku-app.yml // Just a comment
name: Build App on Heroku
on:
  push: // type of event
    branches:
      - master // name of branch we want to listen to for event

jobs:
  heroku-pull-request:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      HEROKU_APP_NAME: my-awesome-app // name of app on heroku

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          ref: ${{ github.ref_name }}

      - name: Login to Heroku
        uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12
        with:
          heroku_email: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_EMAIL }} // Heroku email address
          heroku_api_key: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY }} // Heroku API key
          heroku_app_name: ${{ env.HEROKU_APP_NAME }} // Declared above
          justlogin: true

      - name: Add Heroku remote
        run: heroku git:remote --app=${{ env.HEROKU_APP_NAME }}

      - name: Push to master branch app on Heroku
        run: git push heroku ${{ github.ref_name }}:master --force
```

Visit [Github Actions Secrets Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) to understand how secrets work in Github actions and how to create them.

You can view your Heroku API key by going to the `API Key` section on your [Heroku Account settings](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account) page.