# Continuous Integration for Heroku (while Github and Heroku aren't integrating)

Tags: github, heroku

Has anyone found a work-around for implementing continuous integration with the Heroku-Github integration down?

It seems you could have a 3rd party listen for changes in Github and then communicate that to Heroku... but I'm not sure what that resource would be.

[Heroku and Github : Items could not be retrieved, Internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892543/heroku-and-github-items-could-not-be-retrieved-internal-server-error)
I don’t have enough clout to comment on the above post, so I am creating a new question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/72095654/354577, for example

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/71982279/354577